# iptablesを使っても防げない攻撃について

Tags: postfix, iptables, dovecot

185.234.217.194 のIPよりSMTP SASLのブルートフォース攻撃され、iptablesの設定ファイルとコマンドで、このIPのINPUTポリシーをDROPにもしたのにも関わらず、連続でブルートフォース攻撃をされています。
現在は一時的にPostfixを止めたのですが、常に止めるのも都合上とても嫌なので、解決方法はありませんか?

OS: Debian 10
iptablesはlegecyでは無い方です(nftでも無いです)
他に必要な情報があったら言ってください。

Answer (score 2):

Postfix の方で クライアントアクセスを制限するには `main.cf` を 変更して `smtpd_client_restrictions` に `check_client_access` を次のように追加してください。

```
Ex) smtpd_client_restrictions = 
　permit_mynetworks,
　reject_unknown_client
      :::
  check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/reject_list  ←追加
　permit
```

次に ファイル `/etc/postfix/reject_list` を作成して 「アドレス REJECT」の形式で拒否するIPまたはドメイン名を記述します。

```
Ex)
185.234.217.194 REJECT
spam.example.com REJECT
```

ハッシュDB化して、リロードすれば反映されます。

```
# postmap /etc/postfix/reject_list
# postfix reload
```

Postfixの設定は色々ありますのでマニュアル等を熟読して適切なセキュリティ設定を考えてみてください。

Comment: こんな方法もあったのですね... マニュアルをほとんど読まずに設定していたのですみません...